# Access destination volume in Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-volume

I have created a Docker volume and mounted to a container host. Now I am trying to connect (sh to the container) to the container and access the destination, as mentioned below.

```
"Name": “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”,
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/_data",
            "Destination": "/Host-data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
```

When I tried to access "/Host-data", I am getting message saying "can't cd to /Host-data"

Command:

```
# cd /Host-data   
 (I have tried with "/Host-data", '/Host-data' as well)
```

Is this something not possible? or the steps I am following are incorrect? If this is not correct how can we copy data to this destination and view them?

Comment: Please share more details on how you mounted the volumes and steps you used to debug this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. please find the details how I mounted the volume, $ docker run -d -v <volume name>:/<Destination>  <docker container name>  and then I have ssh to the Docker container and cd to the Destination (/Host-data).

Comment: Maybe better to include that in your question. Also nice to see all the steps from the volume creation, running the container and the debug process. Maybe also use actual values and not `<>`.